# Does AppCompatActivity do not have the new Android M permissions methods

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, appcompatactivity

I want to add **Android M** support to our apps and i followed the Google [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html)

for checking permissions and the requesting them. But i get an error, that those methods are not known by my `Activity`. My `Activity` is extending `AppCompatActivity`.

Could it be, that this class have not implemented yet those new methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [latest source code of AppCompatActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java) you can find that there are no methods yet like `checkSelfPermission()` or `requestPermissions()`. 
So your assumption is right.

Comment: So no fully appcompat support for Android M at the moment?

Comment: Oh no :-( So no way at the moment to add Android M support to apps using AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If You will use actual support library like `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'` there will be no problem